# I am looking for a mathematical method to analyze this graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have a graph where the vertices are cities, and other factors such as climate, country, etc, these graphs share information between them, I need to find a computerized method to analyse not only those relationships but to predict what can happen.

[image]

I thought of neural networks, but if I pass this information to a matrix will lose information.

The graph analysis does not help me, because it analyzes the relationship between two nodes/ vertices, and here the relationship is more complex.

As you see, the information that the different vertices exchange through the edges, they are of different types and of more than one type. For example, City A will have a temperature, a pressure, a different economy linked to another node, it is a lot of information and is complex.
The difference with having this data in a matrix is that there is a relationship between them.

Ideas???